# Number format with SMS Clickatell provider

Tags: sms

I set up a clickatell account and configured it in Civi. It only works if the phone number has a 1 in front for the country code. None of our numbers have the country code, is there a way around this?

Comment: That is the reason we decided to go with Twilio. It was either reformat all of our phone numbers into a format which would be strange for normal usage or go with a different SMS provider.

Comment: It's also possible to do some customization to prepend the country code before sending so you don't have to add it in the UI.  You might need a developer/consultant's help with this but it's certainly been done, and AFAIK works well.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced (and fixed) this problem three days ago for a client by patching the Clickatell extension to prepend the "1" where it doesn't already exist.

In short - someone already wrote this patch, but it only works if you don't have contacts you want to text outside the US and UK.  The patch is referenced on [CRM-14160](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14160) - or just find it [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/2447).

If you're not a developer, but you feel comfortable installing an extension from a zip file, I just made a [Github repo here](https://github.com/PalanteJon/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell) with the patched extension.  That said - I don't want to post it as the "new" Clickatell extension, because it makes some country-specific assumptions.

You can see that I updated the CRM-14160 ticket with what I think is the ultimate solution - which is for CiviCRM to know the country code associated with each country.  Then the Clickatell extension could check for whether it's present or not - and if not, then prepend it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your numbers to include a country code.

This will vary based on the format you've input data, but the below works for the sample dataset used on the demo sites.

```
-- a couple of formats including area code and local number
UPDATE civicrm_phone SET phone = CONCAT('+1 ', phone) 
 WHERE phone LIKE '(___) ___-____';
UPDATE civicrm_phone SET phone = CONCAT('+1 ', phone) 
 WHERE phone LIKE '___ ___-____';

-- local numbers get your assumed area code prepended also
UPDATE civicrm_phone SET phone = CONCAT('+1 555 ', phone) 
 WHERE phone LIKE '___-____';
```

When doing this, make sure to make backups and work on test data so you avoid loss.

There is a trigger `civicrm_phone_before_update` which will handle updating the `civicrm_phone_numeric` column.